# Keep textArea size after switching the tap

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scroll, textarea

I have a simple GUI with multiple tabs like that:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBYBF.png)

The problem is that, after filling the text area up to the bottom ([filled console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qimGB.png)) and switching the tab - it completely breaks the markup ([bottom-broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Mwo.png))

Here is the code example of the textArea and Constraints

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        tabbedPanelOne.add(textArea);
        CustomAppender.setTextArea(textArea);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 10.0;

        Font font = textArea.getFont();
        float size = font.getSize() - 4.0f;
        textArea.setFont(font.deriveFont(size));

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        //textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        layout.setConstraints(textArea, gbc);

        /*
         * Scrolls for TextArea
         */
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        tabbedPanelOne.add(scroll);
        layout.setConstraints(scroll, gbc);
```

`//textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));` works fine, but it disables vertical scroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layout.setConstraints(textArea, gbc);
```

First of all when add a component to a scrollpane you would never attempt to set constraints on the component. A JScrollPane uses its own custom layout manager so you don't do anything special when you add the component to the viewport of the scroll pane.

However, the simplest solution would be to use a BorderLayout on the panel you add to the tab. Something like:

```
JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.add(...);
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
JPanel main = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
main.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
main.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now the scroll pane will take up all the available space in the tab and scrollbars will appear when needed.

Comment: Thank you. BorderLayout works, but I have used setPreferredSize on a scrollpane itself, and it done the trick.

Comment: @OliverJohnson, NOOOO!!! Don't use setPreferredSize()!!! There is no reason to do this. Each Swing component should determine its own preferred size. The layout manager will then either use this information or not. You specify the row/columns of the text area to give the text area a preferred size. The scrollpane will then use the preferred size of the text area. However, in your case it still doesn't really matter because the tabbed pane will look at the size of all panels to determine the size of the panel. The BorderLayout will than adjust the size of the component in the CENTER.